# Strncpy and char **

Tags: c, strncpy

The following code doesnt copy the contents of matches 2 to keys[0].
Why is that so?

```
char **keys;
char matches[2000];
char *matches2;
matches2 =strtok(matches," ");
strncpy(keys[0],matches2, sizeof keys[0]);
```

Comment: `sizeof keys[0]` is `sizeof char*`...

Comment: does not compile that way

Comment: @user3521003: Does not compile what way? nneonneo wasn't suggesting a fix to the code, he was pointing out a problem. Syntactically, it's `sizeof (char*)` rather than `sizeof char*`, but that's *not* the correct size to use. Furthermore, you haven't initialized `keys`, so `keys[0]` is meaningless. Finally, `strncpy()` is rarely the right function to use; see [my rant on the topic](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allocate space for `keys` to point to, as well as space for `keys[#]` to point to.
Also, are you really sure you want to use `strncpy`? It does not guarantee 0-termination, instead copying at most n byte of the ggiven string and 0-filling the rest of the buffer.

The size for a string is the number of elements including 0-terminator: `strlen(s)+1`

For creating a copy of a string, you might look into non-standard `strdup`, a possible implementation:

```
char* strdup(const char* s) {
    size_t n = strlen(s)+1;
    char* r = malloc(n);
    if(r)
        memcpy(r, s, n);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: keys[0]=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    strncpy(keys[matches_number],matches2, 20*sizeof(char));
is this correct? not working ...

Comment: @user3521003: ??? What do you mean to say? Aside: Never cast the return value of `malloc` and the like, it only hides errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this assuming that you already have allocated space for keys[0]

```
strncpy(keys[0], matches2, /*your desired size*/);
```

or

```
strcpy(keys[0], matches2);
```

Comment: And what do you expect `strlen(keys[0]` to be when `keys` hasn't been initialized?